# Maven gives “Resolving Version for Plugin” Error when trying to create a project

Tags: maven, proxy, pom.xml, mahout

I am a newbie to both Linux and Maven. I am trying to get maven working so I can install Mahout. I am having more than just one problem with the process but I will focus on the most basic one:

I am trying to follow [this guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)
to learn how to get started with maven. when I run the following command in the terminal

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

I get the following error:

```
dave@CodeKingdom:~/workspace/maven_test$ mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The metadata /home/dave/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/maven-metadata-central.xml is invalid: end tag name </HEAD> must be the same as start tag <META> from line 1 (position: START_TAG seen ...e/maven/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/maven-metadata.xml"></HEAD>... @1:385) 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.446s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 10 17:43:57 PDT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/310M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Error resolving version for plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin' from the repositories [local (/home/dave/.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginVersionResolutionException
```

I can't make much sense of the resources out there. What I gather based on my googling is that maven is unable to connect to internet to download the necessary artifacts. But I am not sure whether I should modify setting.xml or pom.xml to fix this or whether I should do something completely different. Plus I can't seem to find a pom.xml file in my maven folder. There is a settings.xml file but I am not clear on how or if I should modify it.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703124/plugin-not-found-in-plugin-repository-how-fix-an-issue-when-my-company-nexus-i)?

Comment: @Raghuram hey, thanks for the response. I tried both solutions on the thread you linked but had no success.

Comment: I am getting close to giving up on setting up Mahout properly. It would help a lot if I could just find how to setup Eclipse so I could run Mahout projects. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have internet access from the system?  If so, is it behind a firewall?  If so, you need to update `settings.xml` with `proxy` details.

Comment: @Raghuram I do have internet access. And I just checked network/network proxy on my laptop and proxy is not set so I'm pretty sure I'm not behind a firewall. By the way do you know which pom.xml file I need to edit when trying to get maven working? I have nothing inside the maven folder or its repository but I get a bunch of results when I search outside of it.